# Blocking concurrent requests in Java/Retrofit to same host

Tags: java, concurrency, ninja

I have a Java/Ninja framework web application sending requests to third party API's via Retrofit API.

I have a thread T1, which is generated from thread pool using Ninja framework Schedule annotation (http://www.ninjaframework.org/apidocs/ninja/scheduler/Schedule.html) .
T1 is polling continously to host1 (example.com).

When another thread say T2 starts a request to the same host (example.com), I want T2 to wait till T1 completes its operations and vice-versa.

I checked out http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Dispatcher.html, but looks like the maxRequestsPerHost might not work concurrently.

I tried having a hashMap to modify the hostStatus from each thread and include the status inside synchronzied block, but adding this to multiple methods seems cumbersome.

I'm not sure which concurrency pattern or locking mechanism holds good for this case. Is there a way to add the hostIds to queue or other pattern to implement this behavior.

Comment: Are you polling the host from inside `run` method. If that's the case you can synchronize the `run()` method using static lock and this will only allow a single thread at a time.

Comment: The thread is created via the schedule annotation, http://www.ninjaframework.org/apidocs/ninja/scheduler/Schedule.html . The interval is mentioned via the annotation which acts as a polling job. I do not directly run/control the threads in either case.

Comment: I checked the http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/scheduler.html and IMO class level lock and a global state can help. Global state will be true initially and then set it to false as soon as one of the thread starts polling. When the polling successfully completes set the global state so that other thread who acquired the lock can start polling the host. Also class level lock will ensure synchronization. Make sure to use wait and notify also.

Comment: Why I think class level lock and a global state can help is because as given in the above link since the `@Schedule` annotation is on a method you can have above mentioned logic in that method.
Let me know your thoughts about the same.